# Java applet crashing chrome java on ubuntu when calling javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, applet

Working with chrome on ubuntu, have a basic java applet and javascript interaction.  The javascript to java goes fine, but when I try having the java fire a javascript method, the chrome java plugin crashes.  This all works fine in Fire Fox.

The Error:

```
The following plug-in has crashed: icedTea NPR Web Browser Plugin (using IcedTea6 1.9.7 (6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1~10.04.1))
```

The HTML:

```
<object height='300' id='thisappletawesome' name='thisappletawesome'type='application/x-java-applet' width='550'>
    <param name='classid' value='java:JSHelloWorld.class'> 
    <param name='codebase' value='/java/'> 
</object>
```

The Javascript:

```
function updateWebPage(){
    alert("java is touching me");
    document.thisappletawesome.setText("hihihi")
}
```

The Java:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import netscape.javascript.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JSHelloWorld extends JApplet {
JTextArea txt = new JTextArea(100,100);

public void init(){
    JSObject jso = JSObject.getWindow(this);
    try {
        jso.call("updateWebPage", new String[] {"Hihi"});
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public JSHelloWorld() {
    txt.setText("Hello World");
    getContentPane().add(txt);
}

public void setText(String s)
{
    txt.setText(s);
}
```

Comment: the call from java to updateWebPage (jso.call) has one parameter but the javascript function takes no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks like it was with OpenJDK.

```
sudo aptitude remove icedtea6-plugin
sudo aptitude install sun-java6-plugin
```

Fixed the problem.

Comment: Would you please submit a bug report, either to [IcedTea](http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla/) or to [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/) so they could fix the problem?

Comment: Posted to Ubuntu:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/icedtea-web/+bug/755036

Comment: I made an online example from your code: http://epaul.github.com/stackoverflow-examples/bugreport-examples/ubuntu-755036/example.html Could you try if this gives a problem for you? (I don't have Ubuntu nor Chrome here, so I can't test this now.) It works here in OpenSUSE/IcedTea/Firefox, and does strange things in OpenSUSE/IcedTea/Opera (but does not crash). If it shows the error, I'll add it there.

Comment: So, where is the difference to your applet? I did move the JavaScript call into the start method instead of init, but this should not be the reason. The object tag is the same (but I added some whitespace between the attributes).